# `sfinae</* ... */>` proposal... useful or unnecessary?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I am trying to learn what [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) is. I believe I understand it quite well; however, I do not have a lot of practice in the subject. I mean I would find it difficult to list all the cases in which `SFINAE` should or could be used, or it would be difficult for me to immediately understand what a given sample of an SFINAE code should do. However, I believe I understand the core concept well enough to use it effectively.

Nonetheless looking through examples of SFINAE usage I came to the few conclusions.

One of which is: it is extremely pointless to use a chain of `std::enable_if_t`, `std::void_t`, `std::is_same`, etc, etc, etc, to define a single type `using type = int *`. IMHO (of a "newbie" with untrained eyes) such chains make the code less (extremely less) readable.

The second conclusion was: wouldn't it be useful to have the ability to check few conditions at the same time?

So I created this alias: (well "created" is waaay too big word... I just wrote 4 lines of code...)

```
template<typename T, typename ...>
using sfinae = T;

template<typename T, typename ...>
using SFINAE = T;
```

#### Usage examples

```
// 1) within class declaration:
template <typename T, 
    sfinae<bool,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
    > = true /* provide default option, bc reasons */>
class foo;

// 2) within function declaration:
template <typename T, 
    sfinae<bool,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
    > = true /* provide default option, bc reasons */>
void foo;

// 3) as a function return type:
template <typename T> 
sfinae<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
> const & foo(T const & val);

// 4) To define other SFINAE-conditions as aliases:
template <typename T> 
using check_xyz = sfinae<void,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
>;

template <typename T, typename = check_xyz<T>>
class foo;
```

And my main concern/question is: would a professional c++ developer deem `sfinae</*...*/>` (as I proposed it) useful or extremely unnecessary? Are there any changes that could be introduced to the idea?

Comment: Please turn all `...` into actual code. We review only complete snippets.

Comment: @t3chb0t, but the actual code is `template<typename T, typename ...> using sfinae = T;` and `template<typename T, typename ...> using SFINAE = T;` everything else is just a usage examples... Also because of the keywords "immediate context" (which can be found in cpp draw, the `sfinae` section. Usage of this aliases is limited declarations only. However... I could delete definitions (it would by erase all `...` by an extension).

Comment: **Lacks concrete context:** Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I know, inside templates yes, but there are many `...` elsewhere and I now admit that I didn't see the `// usage examples:` comment. I'd be better if it was a heading so that it's better visible... let me edit this...

Comment: @Mast but... the actual code is: `template<typename T, typename ...> using sfinae = T;` and `template<typename T, typename ...> using SFINAE = T;` Everything related to the `SFINAE` is limited to declarations.There isn't a lot i could do. I "believe" I provided usage examples.

Comment: I think your quesiton is fine after all. Not much code but the rest is just examples that weren't easy to notice. I'll retract my close-vote now... @Mast?

Comment: @t3chb0t thank you for edit. yes... I should separate the code from the examples... I am sorry, I didn't do that in the 1st place.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5, I do not recommend accepting an answer yet. There might be people with even more interesting reviews, though outperforming Arthur is gonna be hard.

Comment: @Incomputable ok... I am sorry... I do not know customs on this side... I am sincerely sorry for messing with you guys.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5, I wouldn't consider this messing. I don't think either of us are interested in reputation at all.

Comment: @t3chb0t It's 4 lines of codes which boils down to a glorified alias. I still have doubts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I just wrote four lines of code...
>
> ```
> template<typename T, typename ...>
> using sfinae = T;
>
> template<typename T, typename ...>
> using SFINAE = T;
> ```

You should have written just *two* lines of code — either the first two or the last two. Not both. "There's more than one way to [spell] it" is the Perl way, not the C++ way. ;) (At least not intentionally! Not intentionally pre-C++2a! Now we're getting both `std::filesystem` and `std::fs`, that's a less airtight position.)

---

As you show, your thing can be used for

```
template<class T, 
    sfinae<bool,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
    > = true>
void foo();
```

However, this is pretty verbose; surely we'd rather write `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>` than `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>`.

So personally I have a different alias that accomplishes the same goal: `bool_if_t`.

```
template<bool B>
using bool_if_t = std::enable_if_t<B, bool>;

template<class T, 
    bool_if_t<
        std::is_integral_v<T> &&
        std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
    > = true>
void foo();
```

This has the advantage that the inner expression is written using normal C++ syntax rules. We don't have to remember some arbitrary rule like "`x, y` means both `x` and `y` must be true"; we just write `x && y`. And if we want to enable this function when *either* `x` *or* `y` is true, we don't have to invent a new primitive; we just write `bool_if_t<x || y>`. `bool_if_t` is much more composable than your `sfinae<Ts...>`, because `bool_if_t` can exploit the existing expression syntax of C++.

---

Recommended viewing: ["A Soupçon of SFINAE"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybaE9qlhHvw) (Arthur O'Dwyer, CppCon 2017). (Yes, that's me.)

You picked examples that don't really show off the power of `sfinae`, by the way.
Consider this example:

```
// 3) as a function return type:
template <typename T> 
sfinae<T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
> const & foo(T const & val);
```

You take a "value-space" boolean (`is_integral_v<T>`), lift it up into "SFINAE-space" with `enable_if_t`, and then apply a logical AND operation in SFINAE-space using your `sfinae` alias.

```
template <typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_integral_v<T> &&
    std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T
> const & foo2(T const & val);
```

Here I take the same "value-space" boolean, perform the logical AND *in value space* where we have a dedicated operator `&&` for maximum expressiveness; and I lift it up into SFINAE-space *after* doing the AND. This is clearer and also probably more efficient in terms of compile time.

Where your version helps is when your values *start* in SFINAE-space!

```
template<class T> 
sfinae<T,
    decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>()),
    T*,
    T&
> const & foo3(T const & val);
```

If we were trying to replicate this code's behavior with the standard tools, we'd say something like

```
template<class, class=void> struct has_plus : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct has_plus<T, decltype(void(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>()))> : std::true_type {};
template<class T> inline constexpr bool has_plus_v = has_plus<T>::value;

template<class T> 
std::enable_if_t<
    has_plus_v<T> &&
    not std::is_reference_v<T> &&
    not std::is_void_v<T>, T
> const & foo4(T const & val);
```

That is, we start with a value in SFINAE-space (`decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())`), lift it into value-space (`has_plus_v<T>`), do the logical AND in value-space, and lift the result back into SFINAE-space.

Whereas with your `foo3`, you start in SFINAE-space, do the logical AND via `sfinae<...>` *without leaving SFINAE-space*, and then you're done. Much simpler! But harder to read, I think.

---

A simple way to improve readability is to pick a good name. `sfinae_space_and<Ts...>` might be clearer. Can you think of a way to write `sfinae_space_or<Ts...>`? How about `sfinae_space_not<T>`? Does it make sense, maintainability-wise, to provide one without the others?

Comment: Incredible how much one can write about four (two) lines of code. Very informative ;-)

Comment: What's the use of `bool_if_t = std::enable_if_t<B, bool>;`? IMO it hides the intent behind it by removing the informative "enable_if" part.

Comment: @Flamefire: I see your point, but OTOH, the "intent" is usually obvious from context. Significantly, `bool_if_t<B>=true` is 8 characters shorter than `enable_if_t<B, bool>=true`. Perhaps most significantly, it eliminates a bikeshed point: if all you have is the low-level `enable_if_t`, then you'll see people writing `enable_if_t<B, XXX>={}` for many different values of `XXX` (bool, int, etc). The slightly-higher-level abstraction eliminates that needless variation. (Murphy's Law: if you don't want people fiddling with the knobs, you have to remove the knobs.)

Comment: Full disclosure: `enable_if_t<B, int>=0` is 4 characters shorter than `enable_if_t<B, bool>=true`, and `int_if_t<B>=0` would be 4 characters shorter than `bool_if_t<B>=true`. Why did I pick `bool`?... I don't know. :P  Maybe I should switch to `int_if_t` as my primitive.

Comment: I don't buy this. Why would you need the assignment/value in `bool_if_t<B>=true`? The 2nd parameter in `enable_if_t` is for the use case of using it as a return value of a function. In class templates you'd use `typename = enable_if_t<foo>`, or in a function parameter `enable_if_t<foo>*=0` So if people use different types for the 2nd param, they probably did not understand how to use this template in the first place. Or am I missing anything? See the last example of @Incomputable for a better example

Comment: @Flamefire: Recommended viewing: ["A Soupçon of SFINAE" (Arthur O'Dwyer, CppCon 2017)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybaE9qlhHvw). (Yes, that's me.)

Comment: @QuuxplusoneI am sorry I made you wait, for soo long, for my response... In fact, I was actually trying to implement `sfinae_space_not<>` and `sfinae_space_or<Ts...>` trying to match your points about `SFINAE-space` and other "pluses" You did mention about `sfinae<t, ts>`. Unfortunately, my attempts boiled down to two cases: (1) detection idiom - converting substitution failure into a `false`/`std::false_type` while performing all logical operations within "value-space", or (2) "trying" to utilize properties of argument packs which also required some sort of conversion type --> bool.

Comment: Neither of these met the requirements set by You (about performing operations in the SFINAE space). Answering the rest of your question, Yes I definitely think that, maintainability-wise, it is a must to provide at least syntax for `not`, `and`, `or` cases. A preferable solution is to allow the "users" to create their own logical statements. Which is something that is impossible to do on types? well, at least I believe so. Now that I think about it, if I can't provide anything like that, the best solution would be to change `sfinae<T, Ts...>` to `sfinae<T, U>`. To check just a single condition

Comment: Oh, I almost forget. Thank you very much for such full, and detailed answer.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5: _"I was actually trying to implement `sfinae_space_not` and `sfinae_space_or` ... Unfortunately [I failed] ... I definitely think that, maintainability-wise, it is a must to provide at least syntax for `not`, `and`, `or` cases."_ Your thoughts parallel mine! :) I'm about 95% sure that it is impossible to write either `sfinae_not` or `sfinae_or`. So, by the laws of syllogism, as you stated: you shouldn't provide `sfinae_and`, either.

Answer (score 9):

### A bit dated...

First of all, let me say that since C++20 much of SFINAE will be unnecessary. Concepts have SFINAE enabled by default, have much nicer syntax, and have greater reuse capabilities.

### Code Review

Personally I don't see much improvement over original one. What I would prefer instead of

```
template <typename T, typename ... >
...
```

is

```
template <typename T, bool ... Conditionals>
... //perform folding
```

Even then, people sometimes have non-trivial logic like AND-ing and OR-ing the results of conditionals.

Much of the complexity lies in that conditional statements, which could be moved away by using something like template variable:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr inline bool supports_xxx = /*is_same, trivial, etc*/;
```

and then people could just use

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<supports_xxx<T>>>
...
```

---

### Example

```
// 1) within class declaration:
template <typename T, 
    sfinae<bool,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
    > = true /* provide default option, bc reasons */>
class foo;
```

is better written as

```
template <typename T>
constexpr inline bool is_int_arithmetic_v = std::is_integral_v<T> 
                                            && std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;

template <typename T, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<is_int_arithmetic_v<T>>>
class foo;
```

Do note the `inline`, it will help users of the code to deal with ODR issues.

Comment: `typename = void_t<things...>` doesn't work if you want multiple mutually exclusive templates. `bool_if_t<things...> = true` works in that case. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybaE9qlhHvw&t=37m00s .

Comment: @Quuxplusone, shouldn't specialization paired with some sort of tag dispatch be used in that case? I believe it also scales better in cases where more than 2 mutually exclusive cases are present. But yeah, my advice is not a good one to make.

Comment: "Shouldn't" is a strong word. ;) I agree that tag dispatch is usually more readable and should be preferred (or `if constexpr` in C++17). But sometimes tag dispatch can't be used; see the video's example of a conditionally `explicit` constructor.

Comment: Review review: It is _"Dated"_ _"**since** C++20"_ because it _"**will be** unecessary"_. Sounds like a plot from Back to the Future IV ;) Anyways, learning SFINAE may still be worthwhile while writing library code that should be backwards compatible and/or useful within older codebases. And compilers still not to catch up a lot 'til they support fully C++20.

Comment: `since C++20` Still a year off! Since `Concepts` were initially proposed for C++11 C++14 and C++17 but dropped before the standard was published I am not going to hold my breath until I see them in the ratified standard.

Comment: @MartinYork: Pedantically, Concepts were only ever in the C++11 (C++0x) draft; they never again made it far enough to get "dropped" from C++14 or C++17. Also, the single least-controversial part of C++2a Concepts is the ability to attach explicit `requires` clauses to functions, which is all OP needs here. A C++2a solution to his problem wouldn't mention the keyword `concept`, just `requires`. And even in the unlikely case that Concepts gets dropped from C++2a, I'm confident that the `requires` keyword would remain in.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T, 
  sfinae<bool,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>
  > = true /* provide default option, bc reasons */>
class foo;
```

vs

```
template <typename T, 
  std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_integral_v<T>
    && std::is_arithmetic_v<T>,
    bool
  > = true
class foo;
```

This version doesn't use your new `sfinae` template, and uses fewer characters, and seems no less functional.

What more in C++20 we'll have named concepts (and failing that) requires clauses.  That will make much SFINAE obsolete.

What more, there are fancier ways to do SFINAE, especially in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)

There is this:

```
template<template<class...>class, class...>
struct can_apply;
```

which tests if a template can be applied to a list of types.

With `constexpr` lambdas that can appear in template non type parameter argument calculations, we can do:

```
template<class F>
constexpr auto apply_test(F &&);
```

which returns an object that, when evaluated on some arguments, returns `true_type` if you can invoke `F` on it, and `false_type` otherwise.

```
template<class T,
  std::enable_if_t<
    apply_test([](auto a, auto b)RETURNS(a+b))( std::declval<T>(), std::declval<T>() ),
    bool
  > = true
>
struct foo;
```

here we test if a type `T` can be added to itself.  (I also use the somewhat ubiquitous `RETURNS` macro)

Or, more cleanly:

```
template<class T>
auto foo( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
requires test_apply(std::plus<T>{})(lhs, rhs)
```

assuming sufficiently SFINAE friendly `std::plus<T>`.